# Any zend tutorial that uses standard folder structure and doesn't use zend tool?

Tags: zend-framework, structure, zend-tool

I want to learn zend without using the zend tool.

I've found some good tutorials but i think they aren't doing the standard botstrapping and folder structure.

Comment: I know you don't want this but still. Take your time to install the Zend_Tool and safe yourself A LOT OF trouble and time later on. http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

Comment: I have never used Zend Tool, I prefer to understand what's going on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation from Zend
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.html

**Standard Structure**
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html

**Modular Structure**
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html